# php display list item from html list

Tags: php

Some one please help me......

My CORD

```
<select name="tables">
<?php if(!empty($_POST['tables'])){

echo  "<option>$_POST[tables]</option>";

}else{

echo "<option>Select</option>";
}
?>
 <option value="vehisys_vehicles">Vehicles</option>
<option value="vehisys_staff">Staff</option>
<option value="vehisys_maintain">Maintain</option>
</select>
```

After post this cord it returns option value(vehisys_vehicles).

How can I display option item (vehicles) in the box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would [**`explode`**](https://www.php.net/explode) the `_`

```
$arrTables = explode("_", $_POST['tables']);
echo  "<option>". $arrTables[1] ."</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish that.

Using `strpbrk`:

```
$result =  strpbrk($value, '_');
```

Using `sscanf`:

```
sscanf($value, '%[^_]_%s', $pre, $result);
```

Using `explode`:

```
$parts = explode('_', $value, 2);
$result = $parts[1];
```

Using [regex](http://www.regexr.com/):

```
$result = preg_replace('/^[^_]+_(.+)/', '$1', $value, 1);
```

or

```
preg_match('/^[^_]+_(.+)/', $value, $matches);
$result = $matches[1];
```

Using `strpos`:

```
$result = substr($value, strpos($value, '_')+1);
```

Using `strstr`:

```
$result = substr(strstr($value, '_'), 1);
```